# Losing internet connection over wifi, "standard gateway not available" on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router

For a few weeks now, I'm losing access to the internet on my laptop every couple of minutes. The wifi itself is stable, just the yellow warning triangle appears and I cannot reach any websites etc.

The issue usually resolves itself after a moment. When I right-click on the wifi icon and click "troubleshoot problems", it checks a couple of things, ultimatively resets the adapter and reports "Standard gateway not available" (with a green check mark for "fixed").

The card is a Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205. Changing the power settings (disabling any power saving features that I could find) does not help.

I also have an Xbox with a wired LAN connection to the same router. Everything is working fine there.

What I noticed is that the problem does not occur as long as I have a VPN connection to our company network.

I've uninstalled my firewall and antivirus software, updated the router and the driver, but no effect. What could cause this problem?

Comment: Try the solution in [this article](http://www.kapilarya.com/the-default-gateway-is-not-available). If this doesn't help, please let us know your exact computer model and BIOS version.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your Xbox to the wireless network for checking if the issue is related to the computer software/drivers and not to the router.

What did you change in the last few weeks to get the issue?

VPN connection "solves" the problem maybe because of tunnel testing packets sent every -+20 seconds by VPN client.

Answer (score 0):

> What I noticed is that the problem does not occur as long as I have a VPN connection to our company network.

Instead of a VPN to your company network, instead try opening a command prompt (Windows-R, cmd) and leave the following running:

ping -t wifi router IP address

If that works, something disconnecting or going to sleep.

If that fails, do the same, but with an internet IP address instead of a local one.

Alternately, try putting your laptop in high performance mode and in both the Wifi adapter's config settings and the Windows power settings, disable all sleep functionality.

After that, log into your router, update the firmware again if there are any more new updates available, and then check through all the pages, particularly advanced pages, for any connection timeouts or other time limits; disable them all.

Make sure the router is on WPA2-AES authentication mode; AES in particular tends to be done in hardware now, and is expected.

As a good general practice as well as a troubleshooting step, buy or borrow a separate Wifi access point (I like the [Ubiquiti Unifi](https://www.streakwave.com/items.asp?Cc=UniFi&iTpStatus=0&Tp=&Bc=) line, though you need to run a controller service for many of the features), wire it to the router like the Xbox is wired, and see if the issue is with the laptop, or with the router's wifi.

As a troubleshooting step, buy a [USB Wifi adapter](http://www.j5create.com/our-products/ethernet-adapters/jue303.html) or use a different wifi card in the laptop.  Use that instead of the laptop's current wifi card to see if you can isolate whether that Wifi card is the issue.

- If the problem goes away when using a different Wifi adapter/card, then there are a few steps to take

  - Just keep using the one that works
  - Buy another wifi card
  - Download BOTH the laptop maker's latest wifi drivers, AND the wifi card maker's latest wifi drivers.

    - Then install the wifi card maker's latest drivers, and see if the problem goes away.

      - If not, go into the card's advanced configuration, and disable everything that looks like SLEEP.
    - If that fails, try the laptop maker's drivers, same steps.
      Likewise, if you have a smartphone or two, or can borrow or find a second laptop or chromebook, use that in as close to the same way as you use the laptop as possible, for an amount of time you'd expect the problem to occur in.

Comment: if it a power setting, just change the power setting:  http://www.stenograph.com/HelpDeskDocs/CaseViewNet/How_to_disable_Power_Management_settings_on_your_WiFi_Adapter.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Constantly pinging the router indeed helps, but switching to high performance mode does not. Any other idea what could cause this?

Comment: By helps, does the constant pinging solve the issue entirely while the ping is happening, or merely reduce the frequency of the issue?  I've added some more steps, but they're starting to be more difficult.

Comment: Yes, the issue is gone with constant pinging. With a USB wifi dongle, everything is fine, so seems to be an issue with the internal wifi chip. Weird though that I didn't have any problems for 2 years before.

Comment: @Niko - I'd recommend buying a new wifi card, but if you want to try something else first, try newer drivers from the wifi card maker first, and the laptop maker second, per updated answer.

Comment: Try opening a windows shell (Start Menu -> cmd [enter]) and then type "arp -a". It should show you a list of IP addresses and their associated MAC addresses, including the one of your router/default gateway, usually the one ending on .1 - try this again when you lost connectivity again and see if the entry is still there. You might also generally check the "arp -a" result when your connection works and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(I tried this answer as comment several days ago but got no response.)</sub>

One solution is included in the article
[[FIX] Intermittent WiFi Connectivity Due To “The Default Gateway Is Not Available” In Windows 8.1](http://www.kapilarya.com/the-default-gateway-is-not-available)

> this problem can be fixed by switching your network adapter driver
>   from Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter to Broadcom 802.11a Network
>   Adapter. By default, the system uses Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter.

The article contains very detailed instructions with screenshots on this
procedure.

Let me know if you are using Broadcom or if this advice doesn't apply to your case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try load your PC using USB stick or liveCD with some live Linux - just for testing - is there the same problem.

The problem sounds as your wi-fi settings in router are incompatible with your windows wi-fi networking...

Is your laptop normally working with wired connection?

And forget about "troubleshoot problems" - it almost doing nothing - just asking "really you have switched router?", "is the cable OK?".